# Ho to implement razorpay payment method in website using javascript

Tags: javascript, razorpay

```
  var razorpay = new Razorpay({
key: "rzp_test_7Cox79AHI5xh6w",
}); 
razorpay.once('ready', function(response) {
console.log(response.methods);

  })

 var options = {
amount: 50000, 
currency: "INR",
receipt: "order_rcptid_11",
payment_capture: '0'
};
razorpay.orders.create(options, function(err, order) {
console.log(order);
});

razorpay.createPayment(options);

razorpay.on('payment.success', function(resp) {
console.log(resp.razorpay_payment_id),
console.log(resp.razorpay_order_id),
console.log(resp.razorpay_signature)}); 

 razorpay.on('payment.error', function(resp){alert(resp.error.description)});
```

I have applied this code to implement the payment system of razorpay  but i am getting error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined. Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

The creation of orders need to happen at the server side. It's stated in the documentation. The client side library is not meant for that and that's why `orders` doesn't exist on `razorpay` object and is coming as `undefined`.

Please refer the following link for more details:-

https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/web-integration/custom/#step-4---create-an-order-in-your

Comment: can you explain me with an example

Comment: Hey Divyanshu. I just went through the docs for razorpay. I have not implemented it. But most probably you can try having an api call from client to server where the server has the GET endpoint inside which there is a function where razorpay instance is used to create orders and return the order object. Now you can return order object as response and use the necessary fields to populate data for createPayment at your client side.

Answer (score 0):

The flow for Razorpay payment is that the front-end calls this

```
var razorpay = new Razorpay(options);
razorpay.open();
```

look at this https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/web-integration/standard/#manual-checkout_

which triggers the handler you pass in the `options`, in your handler function you get `razorpay_payment_id` and other things. You send this to your backend and create the order object there and then verify if the payment using `razorpay_payment_id` and update the order object accordingly.

Note: You don't have to create an order in front-end for making the payment on Razorpay. you will create order on the back-end using the `razorpay_payment_id` and other information obtained in the `handler` function you pass in `options`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script is **loaded** before you call the Razorpay constructor.

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js';
script.async = true;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

OR add this in your HTML

```
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"/>
```

Also, you will need to implement the backend code as mentioned in the docs

[Razorpay docs](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/quick-integration/)